# Что значит ‹‹Накося›› в

Tags: перевод

В самом конце рассказа Чехова "Лошадиная фамилия" есть выражение, которое я никак не могу понять.

> *Накося*!- сказал генерал с презрением и поднес к лицу его два кукиша.- Не нужно мне теперь твоей лошадиной фамилии! *Накося*!

Что значит ‹‹накося››?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2104/what-does-кося-in-phrase-накося-выкуси-exactly-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Накося* (или *накось*) это то же, что и просто междометие "*на*" (бери, получай, take that!) с двумя суффиксами.

Чаще всего *накося* употребляется в сочетании *накося выкуси* (на что собственно намекают и контекст, и жест, сделанный героем рассказа). *Накося выкуси* обыкновенно означает *не получишь*; *даже не мечтай* и т.д.

Подлинный смысл выражения должен быть достаточно понятен, если уделить больше внимания сопровождающему его жесту. Кстати, в английском языке есть более-менее близкий аналог: *bite me!*